# Check if two lists (one is nested) are mutually exclusive

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I want to compare two list (one is nested) for mutual exclusivity. Problem is that this code is printing false even if they have only one element in common. I need it to print false if they have both elements in common.

output I'm getting:
`false true false`

Desired output:
`true true false`

```
...
ArrayList<String> properties = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B"));
ArrayList<ArrayList<String> > pairs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String> >();

pairs.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "C")));
pairs.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("D", "C")));
pairs.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B")));

for(int i = 0; i< pairs.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(Collections.disjoint(properties, pairs.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: Please add a description to your question, for which test data you want which result, including how the current output deviates from your expected results.

Comment: "Problem is that this code is returning  ...." <- The code you posted doesn't contain any return statement. So I would be very surprised if it returned anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I understand your question now after your edit, you are making it too difficult. There is no need for `Collections.disjoint()` here, if you are only looking for *non-equal* lists.
If you want to print `false` if you come across a List with identical contents, why not simply use `equals()`?

So the check becomes

```java
for (int i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++) {
   System.out.println(!properties.equals(pairs.get(i)));
}
```

printing the following output

```
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

## [`Collection.containsAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection))

> I want to compare two list (one is nested) for mutual exclusivity. Problem is that this code is printing `false` even if they have only one element in common. I need it to print `false` if they have **both elements in common**.

If you want to make sure if two Lists having equal size contain the same elements **regardless** of their order, then you can make use of the method `Collection.containsAll()`.

```
List<String> properties = List.of("A", "B");
List<List<String>> pairs = List.of(
    List.of("A", "C"), List.of("D", "C"), List.of("A", "B")
);
        
for (List<String> pair : pairs) {
    System.out.println(!properties.containsAll(pair));
}
```

#### Note

- `equals` method of all implementations of the `List` interface would return `true` only if two lists contain the same elements in the **same order** (if you don't want the order to be taken into account, then `equals` is not suitable for this task).
- Usage of `containsAll()` is justifiable only if the list on which you're invoking this method is **moderate** in size. In this case, it's perfectly acceptable because there are only `2` elements in the list. Otherwise, it would be performance-wise create a `HashSet` based on the `properties` list (if all elements are unique) and perform checks against this set (if there could be duplicates in the list we can generate a `HashMap` of element-frequencies).
- You might want to read [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)